# Specific Database Normalization - Author / Documents

Tags: database, normalization

I'm familiar with database normalization techniques, but I'm struggling with a certain scenario.  I have nearly 100 documents, each having at least one author.  I'd like to create functionality where users can ask for documents specific to authors, specific to years, or simply show all documents ever.  The part I'm struggling with is the request for documents according to an author or authors.

Here's a breakdown of my relations: Author has many documents, document has many authors, document has one year, document has one title.  That's what I have to work with.

Here are my relational tables thus far:

Author Table

```
+----------+-------------+
|   id     |   name      |
+----------+-------------+
|    1     | David Noyce |
+----------+-------------+
```

Document Table

```
+----------+--------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   id     |       title        |  BLOB    |   Year    |   ????    |
+----------+--------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1     |   Car Crashes, WI  |  stuff   |   2013    |     ?     |
+----------+--------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm assuming I want author id(s) to be where my ???? is in my document table, and if each document only had one author, that would probably work nicely, but that's not the case. What's the best way to relate a document to many authors?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add a junction table that allows there to be a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between the documents and authors.

```
documentAuthor
--------------
documentId
authorId
```